# Token received in lambda function returns Unauthorized in APIG

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

These are my first steps in AWS in general and Cognito specifically. So please bear with me as I'm a bit confused by all the concepts and documention is not very easy to follow.

So I set up 3 lambda functions, one that creates a user, one that confirms a user and a last one that is supposed to authenticate the user.

The first 2 work fine, my user is created an confirmed. Now I'm stuck with the 3rd one which is supposed to return a token to be used in APIG, where I've set up a simple endpoint with my cognito authorizer.

Every token I get back returns Unauthorized when tested in the APIG/Authorizers/Cognito Pool Authorizers section.

My 'sign in' code is the following:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  AWS.config.apiVersions = {
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider: '2016-04-18'
  };
  AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
  /*AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'MY_IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
  });*/

  var identityId = null;
  var params = {
    IdentityPoolId: 'MY_IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
    IdentityId: identityId,
    Logins: {
        'login.auth.MYPROJECT': 'MY_USERNAME'
    },
    TokenDuration: 86400
  };

  var cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({
    region: AWS.config.region
  });

  cognito.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return callback(err);
    }
    else {
        /*AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: params.IdentityPoolId
        });*/

        AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
            // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
            var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
            var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
            var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;

            callback(null, {
                identityId: data.IdentityId, 
                token: data.Token,
                accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
                secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
                sessionToken: sessionToken
            });
        });
      }
  });
}
```

Both token and sessionToken return Unauthorized. Can someone tell me what is missing here?

Much appreciated.

**EDIT 2016-11-15**

The 'register' lambda code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'MY_IDENTITY_POOL_ID',    
    });

    var poolData = { 
        UserPoolId : 'MY_USER_POOL_ID',
        ClientId : 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
    };

    var userPool = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider(poolData);
    var email = "myemail+" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1) + "@example.com";
    var params = {
      ClientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID', 
      Password: '1234567890', 
      Username: 'testaccount' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1), 
      UserAttributes: [
        {
          Name: 'email', 
          Value: email
        }
      ]
    };

    userPool.signUp(params, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return;
        }

        callback(null, {
            "message": "Hello from Lambda",
            "data": result
        });
    });
};
```

My 'activate' lambda code is the following:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'MY_IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
    });

    var poolData = { 
      UserPoolId : 'MY_USER_POOL_ID',
      ClientId : 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
    };

    var userPool = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider(poolData);
    var email = "email_address@example.com";
    var params = {
      ClientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID', 
      Username: 'test_username', 
      ForceAliasCreation: false,
      ConfirmationCode: '927000'
    };


    userPool.confirmSignUp(params, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return;
        }

        callback(null, {
            "message": "Hello from Lambda",
            "data": result
        });
    });
};
```

In APIG, I created a **Cognito User Pool Authorizer**, selected my user pool, gave it a name, and set the identity token source to **'method.request.header.Authorization'**.

In my APIG resource under the **Method Request**, I've set Authorization to my Cognito User Pool Authorizer. Additionally, **API Key Required** is set to *true* and I've a couple of keys I was testing with and that caused no issues.

I hope this covers everything.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how these things work together? On the code you listed above, it looks to be entirely Cognito federated identities using developer authenticated identities. Are your first two setting up users in your developer authenticated db (meaning not using user pools)? How did you set up integration between Cognito and API Gatway?

Comment: thanks @JeffBailey - I am not using a custom DB for now, My code is very basic and most of it is hardcoded as you can see in the code above. My goal is to manage user accounts and all related tasks in the backend rather than using the JS client in the frontend.